# Access wamp server outside, not only inside

Tags: apache, http, networking, wampserver

I configured my wamp server to access it online. I add the port 80 in my router, I clicked on the online button in the wamp tray icon. I changed the information from the httd.conf file, but I can only access it from inside my network. For example, with my iphone, I can access it only when it's connected on my wi-fi. With the 3G, an outside network, the server just time out and doesn't respond.

Please can you help me, I need that quick please,

Thank you,

Cedric

Comment: Offtopic, not a programming question.

Comment: @Cedric: This type of question is better suited for ServerFault. That Stack Exchange site is better suited for questions involving the configuration of servers and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing via a public IP address (not a LAN IP)?

Did you also configure Windows Firewall to unblock incoming port 80 requests?

If so, and everything else is correct, your ISP/provider might be blocking incoming port 80 requests.